# How to take a value from a JavaScript file and send it to a PHP file?

Tags: php, javascript

Can you tell me how to take a value from a JavaScript file and send it to a  PHP file?

Code:

```
var year      = (year != null) ? year : '".$this->arrToday["year"]."';


var month     = (month != null) ? month : '".$this->ConvertToDecimal($this>arrToday["mon"])."';


var day       = (day != null) ? day : '".$this->arrToday["mday"]."';


my_window= window.open ('Event.php','mywindow1','status=1,width=350,height=150'); 

\\
```

I want to send the variables (year,Month,day) to Event.php.

Can you tell me how?

Comment: @Pekka: Because Ajax makes Nina cry!

Answer (score 2):

You can use ajax to send JS variables to php (look at [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)), but you can't execute php code through javascript. Another way (if you must use those variable in a new page) is to pass js variables as GET variables something like:

```
my_window= window.open ('Event.php?year=2010','mywindow1','status=1,width=350,height=150');
```

and in php:

```
echo $_GET["year"]; //prints 2010
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = "event.php?year="+year+"&month="+month+"&day"+day;

var win1 = window.open(url,"File name","height=150,width=350,fullscreen=0,location=1,menubar=0,resizable=0,scrollbars=1,status=1,toolbar=0,left=0,top=30");

win1.focus();
```

In event.php file

Use $_GET['day'], $_GET['month'], $_GET['year'] to get the values