# how to pass value from javascript variable to php variable

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my code

Html code:

```
<select name="payflag" id="payflag" onchange="getdata()" class="pay">  
 <option value="1">---Selection---</option>  
 <option value="paid">Paid</option>  
 <option value="unpaid">Unpaid</option>  
</select>
```

Javascript function:

```
<script>  
 function getdata()  
 {  
   var myselect=document.getElementById("payflag").value;  
   alert(myselect);  
 }  
 </script>
```

How to pass `myselect` i.e javascript variable value to php variable(or any php variable)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take a value from a JavaScript file and send it to a PHP file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855910/how-to-take-a-value-from-a-javascript-file-and-send-it-to-a-php-file)

Comment: You can't pass a JavaScript variable value to a PHP variable. However, you can use AJAX to send the JavaScript variable value to a different page where you can access it using `GET` or `POST`.

Comment: dn't know how to do that with AJAX and i want that myselect value in same page.plz help me !!

Answer (score 0):

try using `form.submit()` rather than declaring a new function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 </script>  
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['payflag'])) {
    echo $_POST['payflag'];
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="payflag" id="payflag" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="pay">  
     <option value="1">---Selection---</option>  
     <option value="paid">Paid</option>  
     <option value="unpaid">Unpaid</option>  
    </select>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i try it but its not working.the page get refresh and i want to select the option again but also its not work

Comment: thanks lee for help..the value is get print in variable.but unfortunately the page get refreshed. and again i need to select the option form dropdown list..

Comment: that above  dropdown  box present in form so whatever value i selected from dropdown box must be present..                                                        in short i need that selected option must be their...

Comment: @priyanka so you wanted that the selected value will be the selected one after the page refreshes?